# How do I drop empty strings from a data frame while converting to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, formatting

I am using Juypter notebooks to look at some stock data. That being said, I have come across a weird error which I don't totally understand.

```
time_and_sales['Trade_time'] = time_and_sales['Trade_time'].astype(str)
start, stop, step = 0, -7, 1
time_and_sales['Trade_time'] = time_and_sales['Trade_time'].str.slice(start, stop, step)
time_and_sales['Trade_time'] = pd.to_datetime(time_and_sales['Trade_time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
print(type(time_and_sales['Trade_time']))
print(time_and_sales['Trade_time'].head(10))
```

Here is the code and here is the error

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share sample input with the data where error is occurring.

Comment: There are some invaid date in the column, try setting errors to either ``coerce or ignore`` in [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)

Comment: what do you mean by "*drop empty strings*"? you could convert to datetime with `errors='coerce'`, that will leave `NaT` for inconvertible strings. You can then drop those rows with `dropna()`.

Answer (score 0):

to drop rows from `time_and_sales`, with "empty strings" in `['Trade_time']` try
`time_and_sales.drop(time_and_sales.Trade_time.str.contains('').index, inplace = True)`